# React Native screen navigation on API calls

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-hooks, react-navigation

So, I've been reacting for quite some time. I am facing a problem handling API and making it interact with small widgets in mobile app.

***What I am trying to do ?***

I am on a Screen(A) and on click of a button I go to Screen(B). Simple. Now in Screen(B) I fill up a form and submit it. While the form is submitting I have to show a `Loading` component. Finally the API responds if the request was "Success" or a "Failure".

If it was Success - Navigate back to Screen(A) and show a toast message(Boom..boom..) on screen(A).

If it Failed - Be in Screen(B) and show a toast message(yes, with a failure message).

***My Approach***

Let's start with reducers. I have following reducer state -

```
{
    forSubmitRequest: false, // false - API has been trigerred to submit form
    formSubmitRequestOver: true, // true - request is over
    formSubmitRequestStatus: true // true - success
}
```

Now my actions are as follows -

```
    case FORM_SUBMIT_REQUEST:
      return {
        ...state,
        formSubmitRequest: true,
        formSubmitRequestOver: false,
        formSubmitRequestStatus: false,
      };
    case FORM_SUBMIT_REQUEST_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state, 
        formSubmitRequestOver: true, 
        formSubmitRequestStatus: true
      };
    case FORM_SUBMIT_REQUEST_FAILED:
      return {
        ...state,
        formSubmitRequestOver: true,
        formSubmitRequestStatus: false,
      };
    case FORM_SUBMIT_REQUEST_DOWN:
      return {
        ...state, 
        formSubmitRequest: false, 
        formSubmitRequestOver: true
      };
```

Here's my coding logic in Screen(B)

```
const [formSubmitReq, setFormSubmitReq] = useState(false);
const [showErrorFormSubmitToast, setShowErrorFormSubmitToast] = useState(false);


useEffect(() => {
  if (showErrorFormSubmitToast) {
    Toast.show({
      type: 'error',
      text1: 'Error',
      text2: 'Could not submit.',
      topOffset: ResponsiveSize(0),
      onHide: () => {
        setShowErrorFormSubmitToast(false);
      },
    });
  }
}, [showErrorFormSubmitToast]);

if (
  formSubmitReq &&
  props.teacher.formSubmitRequest &&
  !props.teacher.formSubmitRequestOver
) {
  return <Loading msg="Submitting form..." />;
}
if (
  formSubmitReq &&
  props.teacher.formSubmitRequest &&
  props.teacher.formSubmitRequestOver
) {
  if (props.teacher.formSubmitRequestStatus) {
    props.navigation.goBack();
    return <></>;
  } else {
    setFormSubmitReq(false);
    setShowErrorFormSubmitToast(true);
    props.handleCreateFormSubmitDown();
  }
}
```

Logic in Screen(A)

```
const [showSuccessFormSubmitToast, setShowSuccessFormSubmitToast] =
    useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (showSuccessFormSubmitToast) {
      Toast.show({
        type: 'success',
        text1: 'Success',
        text2: 'Successfully submitted.',
        onHide: () => {
          setShowSuccessFormSubmitToast(false);
        },
      });
    }
  }, [showSuccessFormSubmitToast]);

  if (
    !showSuccessFormSubmitToast &&
    props.teacher.formSubmitRequest &&
    props.teacher.formSubmitRequestOver &&
    props.teacher.formSubmitRequestStatus
  ) {
    console.log('Prep show toast');
    setShowSuccessFormSubmitToast(true);
    props.handleCreateFormSubmitDown();
  }
```

Lastly this function - `handleCreateFormSubmitDown` just fires action - `FORM_SUBMIT_REQUEST_DOWN`

Gist of the code ->

I am trying to show Toast on Screen(A) only when request was success and request was actually fired. Not it may happen that request was success and I came back to Screen(A) now I simply navigate to Screen(B) so I have to make sure toast isn't visible as request wasn't fired. Now when reducer state updates then Screen(A) also gets rendered causing some nast things.

Can anyone point out what strategies they follow in such scenarios and where I could improve here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to utilize [route params from `react-navigation`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/#updating-params)

In screen B

```js
...
useEffect(() => {
  // Navigate to screen A with a route param
  navigation.navigate(A, { displaySuccessToast: true });

}, [showSuccessFormSubmitToast])
```

In Screen A

```js
...
useEffect(() => {
  if (route.params.displaySuccessToast) {
    Toast.show({
        type: 'success',
        text1: 'Success',
        text2: 'Successfully submitted.',
        onHide: () => {
          // Hide Toast Action
        },
      });
  }
}, [route.params]);
```

Other wise you can use a global state management solution like [redux](https://redux.js.org/)

Its the same logic. You need to update a flag in the global state. Then navigate to the earlier screen and check if this flag is set and render the toast message.

Comment: can you please elaborate on how Redux can be used to solve ? The solution you provided becomes kind of messy when suppose i need to show toast from a screen say 5 layers deeply nested.

Comment: Its the same logic for redux. Set a boolean flag in global state to mark this once submitted & navigate to the desired screen. Then check whether this flag is set in redux store and render the toast message & reset the flag again.